# Call Asp.Net webforms server control method using jQuery .ajax method

Tags: jquery, webforms, servercontrols

I'm trying to create a web forms server control and really wanted to leverage jQuery to handle the client side interaction.

So far I've not found any examples to being able to directly call a server control using the jQuery .ajax functionality and I'm wondering is it even possible?

I know I could go down the web service or Http Handler route but my aim is to create a control that can be dropped into existing sites and utilise session but with no intention of needing to use ViewState.

Can this be done? or do I have to use the ScriptControl and Asp.Net Ajax functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

Probably the closest is to create an HttpHandler class and include it in your server control's DLL.  Then, you'll only need a single line added to your web.config to wire the handler class up to an endpoint that jQuery can communicate with.

Comment: Thanks for that Dave, I hadn't considered a Http Handler included with the server control. I shall have to give that a go.